# Fitnesse- Error refactoring a page

Tags: fitnesse

HI, Everytime I try to refactor a page I get the following error-
Cannot rename FitNesse.StoreProcedure to TestSuite.StoreProcedure
TestSuite.StoreProcedure is not a valid simple page name.
Due to this I am having trouble creating a test suite. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail?

Comment: I created a parentpage and now planning to rename some existing pages to create childs of that parent page so that I can include them in the parent page and run as testsuites. I am getting above mentioned error while renaming those child pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to move the page from one sub-wiki to another rather than rename it?

The Refactor tab allows you to delete, rename or move a page.

To rename your `FitNesse.StoredProcedure` to `FitNesse.TestStoredProcedure` you enter `TestStoredProcedure` in the rename field.

To move your page to a different sub-wiki - say from  `FitNesse.StoredProcedure` to `TestSuite.StoredProcedure`, enter `TestSuite` in the move field.

Comment: The Move - is the one I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help